Creating an EF migration for a SQL script
I have created a SQL script file with a bunch of insert's into a table if the values do not already exist.
It's made up with a series of:
INSERT INTO Departments (Number, [Name])
    SELECT 3, 'TOPS'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Number FROM Departments
                      WHERE Number = 3)

I have been asked if I can create a migration script in Visual Studio Entity Framework so that other devs can run it using EF code-first and calling the update-database command.
I have no idea how to create a migration script to run this. Any pointers appreciated.

The documentation is always a good place to start...

EF with .NET or .NET Framework?

@YungDeiza We are using .Net 8

@ZoharPeled the docs here would be good if I hadn't already spent hours building my sql script file. (usually we have just run the script via SSMS). Is there a way I can point the create-migration command to my script file and the magic happens.

You should probably use the built in data seeding functions. Add a .HasData call to your dataContext file, i.e.
modelBuilder.Entity<Departments>().HasData(new Department{Number = 3, Name = "TOPS"});

and use the regular Add-Migration command to generate a migration. You could also add an empty migration and manually insert migrationBuilder.Sql(...) to run arbitrary sql code.
See Migrations overview for a general overview of the migration concept

Based on your comment on the question, it appears that you want to be able to use already-prepared SQL code specifically. In that case, you can simply generate an empty migration and then execute some arbitrary SQL. Here's an example migration from a current project of mine:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace SI.Gbrmpa.Eotr.Model.Migrations
{
    public partial class MergeFluorescingBleachingSeverityIntoPaleInReefHealthAndImpactSurveyCoralBleachingObservation : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            DatabaseUpdater.DataManager.MergeFluorescingBleachingSeverityIntoPaleInReefHealthAndImpactSurveyCoralBleachingObservation(migrationBuilder);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            // Changes cannot be rolled back.
        }
    }
}

and here's the DatabaseUpdater.DataManager class:
public static class DataManager
{
    public static void MergeFluorescingBleachingSeverityIntoPaleInReefHealthAndImpactSurveyCoralBleachingObservation(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(Properties.Resources.MergeFluorescingBleachingSeverityIntoPaleInReefHealthAndImpactSurveyCoralBleachingObservation);
    }
}

That resource is a string containing SQL code.
You can do basically the same thing, with or without the additional class, and the SQL can he hard-coded or whatever. You'd obviously also want to provide a rollback mechanism if at all possible. This one required manual intervention but we have others that downgrade automatically.

You can create an empty migrations
Add-Migration "My INSERT INTO"
public partial class Mynewemptymigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        @"INSERT INTO Departments (Number, [Name])
        SELECT 3, 'TOPS'
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Number FROM Departments
                  WHERE Number = 3)"
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
         //Rollback here
    }
}

Update-Database --your options

This wouldn't even compile...

I managed to get it to work finally with:
public partial class ChangePKOnPoLines : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        var PoLines = Path.Combine("SQLScripts/changePKOnPoLines.sql");
        migrationBuilder.Sql(File.ReadAllText(PoLines));
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
}

